# Two different sites, same IP, same top-level domain, on IIS 7.5 -- one works and the other displays HTTP 404 error

Tags: iis, iis-7, domain, ip, iis-7.5

I'm running a Windows 2008 R2 box with IIS 7.5 as the web server.

On IIS, I have two websites: mysubsite1.mysite.com and mysubsite2.mysite.com.  There is only one IP on the server and both sites share this IP.  Here is how I have the bindings configured:

[image: mysubsite1]

[image: mysubsite2]

mysubsite1.mysite.com works fine.  However, mysubsite2.mysite.com gives me the following error:

> Not Found
>
> HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Now, if I change the Host name field for mysubsite1.mysite.com to blank and restart the web server, both sites work!

[image: mysubsite1.1]

The question is why is the host name field for the first site causing an HTTP 404 error for the second site when both sites' Host name fields are filled?

I would appreciate any insight.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you verify that you don't have a typo your DNS records anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of leaving the address to "All Unassigned", set it to the shared IP address for both sites.

Answer (score -2):

My first thought is that it's a port-error. You seem to try to connect to two different sites on the same port and that just doesn't work. Your first site, mysubsite1 uses the default http-port 80 and works fine. However, when you try to access mysubsite2 on port 80 you get an error simply because mysubsite2 doesn't exist on that port.
What you need to do is to create a virtual host on a different port (8081 and upwards are often used).

Comment: Thank you very much. If it's a port error, as you say, then why would taking off the host name for mysubsite1 fix the problem?  And I thought the bindings look at IP, port, and hostname to determine the appropriate response and to where the request is mapped.

Comment: Without knowing too much about IIS I would say that taking of mysubsite1 would "free" up port 80. The bindings does exactly as you say, the problem is you have told it to "find mysubsite2 on port 80". But there is no mysubsite1 on port 80 and that gives you an error.

Comment: Thank you.  Well, both sites operate fine when the first site has no host name bound.  If I bind the host name for both sites, then the second site breaks.  If I understand your explanation correctly, the second site should break, no matter what, because it also exists on port 80.  But that's not what's happening here.

Comment: @Sandokan -1 This *should* work just find as long as you have host headers configured (think of them like Apache Named Virtualhosts). If you don't know much about IIS, you should think twice about answering IIS questions :)

Comment: So that means that my answer is completely wrong and thus should be downgraded?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what a downvote is for - an incorrect answer.

Comment: @Sandokan - uhh yes, your answer is wrong, and wrong answers generally get downvotes. Try not to take it personally, just move on to the next question and try again :)

Comment: Like I said, you can bind multiple websites to the same port as long as you have a host header configured for each site's binding. This is the same principle that lets Apache run multiple websites on the same IP/port combo using named virtualhosts. You still only have a single process bound to port 80 (IIS), but doing this allows it to handle running multiple sites on the same IP/port combo.